# setInterval very slow in standalone flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

setInterval function in Flash works fine with builtin flash player (testing phase) but when I use same (published) swf on standalone player it is almost 10 times slower than that. To confirm i created a simple counter without any graphics and noticed this issue.

PS: I have checked on various player versions and even on internet browsers and even on VMWare on windows 7. I tried all other options like cpu and gpu acceleration but no improvement.

My testbench:only one frame and one dynamic text field with name "te". following is the action script

```
var lo=0;
function f():void{
    te.text=lo++;
}
setInterval(f,0);
```

Comment: good news for you anyway setInterval is deprecated and has been for years so don't use it.

Comment: Deprecated?! How you imagined that? **Absolutely not true**!

Comment: `setInterval` with **ZERO**?!? What you expect to happen? Keep updating this FOREVER?! :D

Comment: An interval of 0ms is not a good idea. Intervals (both `setInterval` and `Timer`) are not that accurate and will dispatch near the frame updates (at 30fps that's every 33ms). [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

Comment: Not a good idea is **very softly said**! What this actually means it that it would try to call `f` as many times as possible within one frame. But because of the nature of AS, the frame rate will drop as much as possible, because the actions inside it aren't finished yet. So next frame switching is delayed in order to execution to finish, but in your scenario **it never finishes**...

Comment: in the official as3 docs they don't say deprecated but they certainly advise the user to consider using Timer instead. Fair enough it's not deprecated but following the official docs I still can say "consider using Timer instead as advised in the official docs"

Comment: @BotMaster: word. @Andrey Popov: it is AS3.-- the `Timer` Class is more comfortable. There are many advantages.

Comment: They are language features and what's more comfortable depends on both the situation and the developer. You **cannot** say "do not use it", nor it's right to say it's deprecated because it's not. The one that asks the question simply isn't using it properly, it's not `setInterval`'s problem..

Comment: 0 in interval is intentional for the performance measurement, that how fast can it go.

Comment: Performance measuring.. what? Please guys, let's close this question..

Answer (score 0):

The true answer here is that you are using `setInterval` with a value of `0`. Which means that you want to do as many possible calls to the function `f` in a frame as possible. But because of the nature of AS3, the frame switching is delayed so that the code inside can be executed (frame rate drop). But you never finish executing - your `setInterval` keeps going forever and is busting up everything. It's like writing `while (true)` loop..

So just start using it properly and you won't have any problems.

Comment: 0 in interval is intentional for the performance measurement, that how fast can it go. The problem is related to stand alone player. I cant understand the performance difference between internal and external flash players

Comment: How fast can it go?! What do you expect to happen - no matter which player you use, it will eventually freeze..

Comment: And I don't even understand how can you compare it to "built in flash player" :)

Comment: you can try... it works, i mean its not freezing... "builtin flash player" means the player used for debugging inside flash CC (when you press ctrl+Enter)

Comment: plz try at your end and tell me what happens

Comment: The fact that you are asking here what's wrong means **it is not working**! There is no way to call this a benchmark - what are you actually measuring? What's the frame rate when you do constant calls to a function? Do `while(true)` loop and say it's slower.. `setInterval` calls a function. It's **NOT** said it would be at a regular interval, so there's no really way to measure it's performance AT ALL!

Comment: Yes, `setInterval(f, 0)` is not the same as `while(true)`, but it's equally impractical. An endless loop blocks the AVM thread, but a 0ms interval is somewhat like an `enterFrame` handler, since intervals are executed "near" frame updates, 0ms is well below the frame rate and will execute approximately on the next available frame indefinitely. Anything that affects the frame rate (a well known difference between stand-alone and plugin player) will affect your code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use flash Timer class to precise interval time,
it works more efficent compared to ENTER_FRAME or setInterval

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1); //ms
var time = 0;
myTimer.start()
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandle);

function timerHandle(e:TimerEvent){
    txt_time.text = time.toString();
    time++;
}
```